# Primary Key Constraint issue with API request inside an Email Message

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql, .net-core

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_EmployeeBulletinView'.
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EmployeeBulletinView'.
The duplicate key value is (44122, 67489).
```

this error is showing up even when I check if the EmployeeBulletinView exists.
currently the call looks like:

```
EmployeeBulletinView employeeView = await _context.EmployeeBulletinView.FirstOrDefaultAsync(v => v.EmployeeID == employeeID && v.BulletinID == bulletinID);
if (employeeView == null)
{
 employeeView = new EmployeeBulletinView();
 employeeView.BulletinID = bulletinID;
 employeeView.EmployeeID = employeeID;
 employeeView.EmployeeBulletinViewDate = DateTime.Now;
 _context.Add(employeeView);
 return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
}
return true;
```

to get to this database call, a url of an api controller is passed in as an IMG source to record that the recipient has viewed the bulletin. is it possible that the email client that caused the error sent a request twice at the same time to the point that the first one has successfully saved the record but the second one is creating the EmployeeBulletinView object still and is in the process of saving?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how are your entities configured?

Comment: @DanielA.White it is a composite PK. it currenty looks like `builder.Entity<EmployeeBulletinView>().HasKey(view => new { view.EmployeeID, view.BulletinID }); ` and the object itself looks like: `public class EmployeeBulletinView
    {
        [Required]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        
        [Required]
        public int BulletinID { get; set; }

        public DateTime EmployeeBulletinViewDate { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Have you checked the data? Does this happen with any record?

Comment: @PabloRecalde the data is fine and yeah it happens with other records as well.